# How to fix warning openerp.wizard on openerp 6

Tags: python-2.6, wizard, openerp-6

openerp.wizard: The wizard base_report_creator.report_filter.fields uses the deprecated openerp.wizard.interface class.
It must use the openerp.osv.TransientModel class instead.

What is the correct way to fix this warning?

Comment: You should check and corrigate the Class definition. Are you sure the super class is `osv.TransientModel`?

Comment: the TransientModel is define in orm Class and osv import orm from openerp.osv.orm import MetaModel, Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel